# What are all of these statistics and probability symbols?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

Given a sample space $\mathcal C=\{c:0<c<10\}$ with $C \subset \mathcal C$. The probability function is $$P(C)=\int_C \frac{1}{10} dz$$ and the variable $X(c)=c^2$. Find the CDF $F(x)$.

By an example in the text, it seems that $F(x)=P(x)$. So the CDF should be $$\int_0^{10} \frac{1}{10} dz = 1.$$
There are several problems here. If it equals one, then it's a cumulative function (rather than distrib function) and the book says the answer is $F(x) = \frac{\sqrt x}{10},\ 0<x<100$.

Something is being lost. $F(x)$ is not the same as $F(c)$ and $c=\sqrt x$ gives the right answer. But why? What is $X$ vs $x$? What is $F(x)$ vs $F(c)$? Or what am I misunderstanding (I'm not even sure what to ask here, so you can just say anything useful).

P.S. I did read the text, but it's rather terse and no examples explain the rationale behind why the integral is done on $\sqrt x$.

Comment: The CDF of the random variable $X$ is by definition the function $F$ such that $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$. (Note that $X$ is a random variable, i.e. a function on the sample space $\mathcal{C}$, but $x$ is simply a real number.) In your example, the event $X\leq x$ is equivalent to the event $c^2\leq x$, which is in turn equivalent to $-\sqrt{x}\leq c\leq\sqrt{x}$ (assuming $x\geq0$). So $F(x)$ equals the probability that $c$ is between $-\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{x}$. And how do you calculate *that* probability? Use the definition of $P(C)$ for some subset $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 4):

The CDF of a random variable $X$ is the function $F(x) = P(X \le x)$. In this case

$$\{X \le x\} = \{c \in \mathcal C : X(c) \le x\} = \{c \in \mathcal C : c^2 \le x\} = \{c \in (0,10) : c \le \sqrt x\}. $$

So

$$ \{X \le x\} = \begin{cases}
(0, \sqrt x] &\text{if } 0 < x < 100 \\
\varnothing &\text{if } x < 0 \\
(0,10) & \text{if } x > 100
\end{cases}.
$$

Assuming $0 < x < 100$ we have

$$P(X \le x) = P((0,\sqrt x]) = \int_0^{\sqrt x} \frac1{10} \,dz = \frac{\sqrt x}{10}. $$

Comment: What is X versus C? I know C is the sample space and X is the random variable. But what's the difference?

Comment: @Jeff $\mathcal{C}$ is the sample space: a sample space is just a set on which we've declared some collection of subsets to be measurable. $X$ is a random variable: a function from $\mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{R}$. More precisely, $X$ is a measurable function: for every interval $(a,b] \in \mathbf{R}$ the preimage $\{c \in \mathcal{C} : X(c) \in (a, b]\}$ is a measurable set in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: FYI: I haven't forgotten about this! Still trying to wrap my head around it. The answer is clear as day when I read it, but there's still something missing in my head.